# ¿Cómo poner una imagen de fondo en?

Tags: python, imagen, interfaz-gráfica, pyqt5

Me gustaría saber ¿Cómo pongo una imagen de fondo a la ventana creada con PyQT5? Muchos me dicen que use **Designer**, pero estoy evitando usarlo. ¿Conocen alguna manera?

Comment: En que tipo de widget lo deseas poner, podrias colocar tu codigo.

Comment: @eyllanesc, Creo que no es necesario. Lo quiero poner en la ventana (MainWindow). 
Me gustaría sacar ese fondo gris y cambiarlo por una imagen que estuve armando. Si aún necesitas el código, avísame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias formas de realizar esa tarea:

1. Usando [Qt Style Sheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html):

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QMainWindow()
    w.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-image: url(/path/of/image)}")
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2. Usando [QPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html):

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QMainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    background =QPixmap("/path/of/image")
    # background = background.scaled(w.size(), Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio)
    pal = w.palette()
    pal.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush(background))
    w.setPalette(pal)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```